# Is it 'echar', 'tirar' or 'lanzar indirectas'?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, modismos

I have read and heard this idiomatic expression in several ways. Is there a more proper or correct idiomatic expression for this?

Which one is the correct idiomatic expression?

- echar indirectas
- tirar indirectas
- lanzar indirectas

Comment: In Colombia you will hear almost always **echar**, less often **tirar** and never **lanzar**

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [Meer Meer's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/33067/1674), this seems to be location dependent. In the north of Spain, I am more used to "lanzar indirectas", although "tirar indirectas" is also fine. "Echar" sounds less correct.

Google and Linguee seem to have a similar amount of results for "lanzar indirectas" and "tirar indirectas".

Comment: I believe that might be right. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It will probably be "Tirar indirectas" here in informal Buenos Aires, may be "lanzar", and almost sure it won't be "echar indirectas". So +1 to location-dependent. Qué difícil es hablar el español.

Answer (score 2):

It depends of the country or context, but the correct option for all cases is "lanzar indirectas", because its not ambiguous and is more propper, Here some examples:

https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/lanzar+indirectas

Comment: In Medellin you will hear almost always **echar**, less often **tirar** and almost never **lanzar**. Looks like in Bogotá is the other way around. Is it?

Comment: Yes, but "echar" sounds bad for international spanish, because that word means to be dismissed or fired from work

Comment: That's interesting to hear of. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Ok. I understand, but I don't think "international Spanish" exists. There are lots of examples of what you might think as international spanish that will get you in "trouble" in some places, i.e.:  _coger_ _chaqueta_, etc If you say *lanzar indirectas * in Medellín it will sound weird, however it will be understood.  Anyway +1 

Comment: A propósito _echar_ no solo significa despedir. En el diccionario aparecen 48 acepciones.. La definición 24 es _decir, proferir_ y la 25 menciona _echar maldiciones_ que es muy similar a _echar indirectas_  ver https://dle.rae.es/echar

Comment: No he dicho que solo significa despedir, pero es el uso mas correcto que tiene, en ese contexto de palabras, también se usa "echarse crema" por ejemplo, pero es incorrecto, se debería escribir, "aplicarse crema", pero aun así la gente lo dice...

Comment: uy que pena pero *echarse crema* **es correcto**. RAE Acepción 9. tr. Poner, aplicar. Echar aceite a las bisagras. Echar ventosas.

Answer (score 1):

**Echar** and **lanzar** are both correct, but I think **tirar indirectas** is the correct expression and the one you will hear more often.

For example, a very common phrase you will hear among students:

> ¿No te fijaste? ¡Esa chica te estaba **tirando la onda**!

Means something like

> *Didn't you notice? That girl was **all over you***

in the sense of being passively trying to catch his attention.

I hope this answers your doubt.

Comment: Thanks RubioRic for the corrections. I'll try to be more mindful of my writing.

Comment: Not sure where is Meer Meer from - in Buenos Aires you say `tirando onda` instead of `tirando LA onda`. Well - `tirando LA onda`, with emphasis on the `LA`, would mean they are `tirando onda` REAAAAAAALY much.

Comment: Guess it is a matter of regionalisms. "tirando onda" doesn't feel like a complete phrase over here. "tirando la onda" makes a lot more sense for us. But then again, Argentina might be different. Thanks for the feedback.